# One IIS server, multiple domains with SSL, one not working

Tags: ssl, iis-6, https, timeout

i have a webserver IIS 6.0. I have multiple domains running, some of them with SSL. All of a sudden, one of my domains with SSL is timing out. When i call it http is runs fine.

I am very confused since all my other websites with SSL are working fine, but just this one is failing.

Remember, all the websites are in the same IIS server, same IP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a good host header configure on the Web Site. Check the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true)